# Ruby and large hashes: when to expect performance degradation? Hash with 800K keys running very slow

Tags: ruby, hash

We understand there is no fixed rule on how many items Ruby hashes can accommodate before losing constant time access, but we're hoping someone can share some advice.

We are storing 800K keys in a Ruby hash, and assigning them all a boolean value of true. That's it.

Each lookup seems to take a few seconds.

Should Ruby hashes exhibit constant time lookup with 800K keys?

Is there a threshold or rule-of-thumb for when to expect performance degradation with large hashes? We would love to hear from a Ruby expert.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of keys are you using? Symbol keys will have a much faster lookup than string keys.

Comment: we are using string keys

Comment: The `String` class in Ruby has a large API and some overhead in intializing. @sevenseacat is spot-on - use symbols, as this is exactly the kind of case where they are best used.

Comment: see this article http://www.platanus.cz/blog/working-with-huge-hashes-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

As well as converting your strings to symbols using s.to_sym, provided you are not creating or destroying hash keys during a sequence of multiple lookups, you could also call GC.disable before and GC.enable after a set of lookups. This will temporarily disable garbage collection, and it is relatively safe to do this if you are running e,g. a simple loop that doesn't create or delete large numbers of objects.

Ruby performance can degrade significantly when the count of (Ruby) objects in memory gets into the millions. Some of the performance loss is the time it takes the garbage collection routines to take stock.

Comment: how about 800K objects? would you expect a hash of 800K symbols (storing only booleans as values) to still yield constant time lookups?

Comment: Hash lookups aren't technically constant time, but provided you are in  a reasonable space otherwise, its more like log(n). Yes I've worked with similar sized structures in Ruby and I have just checked this on my laptop, benchmarked a million hash lookups for an 8000 item hash at roughly 6 seconds, and an 800000 item hash at roughly 7.5 seconds